# Finding values $a$ and $b$ which transforms a differential equation

Tags: partial-derivative, systems-of-equations

Given the function $u = u(\xi, \eta)$ where $\xi = x + ay$ and $\eta = x + by$, find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that they transform the equation $$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2
}} + 4\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x\partial y}+3\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} = 0$$
into
$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\xi\partial\eta} = 0$$

I have managed to get the differential equation down to: $$(1+4a+3a^{2})\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\xi^{2}} + (1 + 4b + 3ab)\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\xi\partial\eta} + (1+4a+3ab)\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\eta\partial\xi}+(1+4b+3b^{2})\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\eta^{2}} = 0$$

Now I am not told about the continuity of this function so I assume I can't use clairaut's theorem hence I must solve the following system:$$\begin{cases} 1 + 4a + 3a^{2} = 0 & (1)\\ 1 + 4b + 3ab = 1 & (2)\\ 1 + 4a + 3ab = 0 & (3) \\ 1 + 4b + 3b^{2} = 0 & (4)\end{cases}$$

From $(1)$: $1 + 4a + 3a^{2} = 0 \iff a = -1 \text{ or } a = -\frac{1}{3}$.

If $a = -1$, $(2) \implies b = 0$ whereas $(3)\implies b = -1$. So clearly I have done something wrong since they do not agree. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the mistake is,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}
 = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta \partial \xi}
$$
and therefore you only get 3 equations: top and bottom as you wrote, and the thirs equation comes from adding LHS and RHS of (2) and (3) together to form one equation.

Comment: Yes but we can only do this when the function is continuous at this point and we don't know so you can't. Even doing so you still get the wrong answer.